# Exploratory Data Analysis using XLMiner

Tags: references, excel, exploratory-data-analysis

I am new to Analytics, I am trying to understand how to use XLMiner for performing exploratory data analysis.

Kindly suggest me any reference to learn more about this. Since I am new to this I am struggling on where to start with.

Comment: Welcome to CV! While the question is definitely in line with the theme of the community, it is very easily answered through a quick search. XLMiner capabilities are documented on the Solver website, and how to do exploratory analysis is a topic that is both very broad and very widely covered in all sorts of places. In the future, please search before asking, and be more specific in your questions.

Comment: @AlexFirsov Thanks for your response. As I'm learning on my own about EDA and XLMiner. I'm trying to find better resource to understand the application of XLMiner for EDA.